# Display user name in a page

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input text area where the user enter his name and i want his name to be shown in another page.

This is what i've tried so far:

HTML of the form:

```
<html>
<form method="post" name="input" action="name.php" >
Name:<br/>
<input name="user" type="text"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="insert" />
</form>
```

name.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Connection Failed");
mysql_select_db("user")or die("Connection Failed");
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$query = "INSERT INTO test(user)VALUES('$user')";
if(mysql_query($query)){
echo "inserted";}
else{
echo "fail";}
?>
```

and the page where i want the name to be shown:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');
mysql_select_db('user');

echo $user;

mysql_close(); 
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So do you have any error..?

Comment: **Danger**: 
You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before printing the value for $user with `echo $user;`, you've to fetch its value either from database with a `SELECT` query or from the `SESSION` Right now you're opening a connection to the database on the page where you want to print `$user` but are not fetching data from the table. `$user` has no value assigned here.

Comment: I've tried using `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` before the 'echo $user;'. Nothing changed.

Comment: @FelipeGrinsztajn are you sure you started session before assigning `$user = $_SESSION['user']`?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't done *anything* to populate the `$user` variable in the final page.

You need to make an SQL query or read some form data.

(You also need to defend against [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting))